# Bootstrap input-group-prepend: mismatched sizes and rounded corner

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-5

i am experiencing issues with the bootstrap class 'input-group-prepend'.

The prepended #-icon container has a wrong height and the right corners are rounded, although the left corners of the following input field get squared (as expected.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhidY.png)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <label for="linkdev_id" class="sr-only">ID</label>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"><img src="./sym/hash.svg" width="20" height="20"></span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" minlength="6" maxlength="6" name="linkdev_id" id="linkdev_id" class="form-control" placeholder="ABCDEF" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

tried to remove the label and replacing the svg in it, but no effect

Comment: If you're using bootstrap 5, `input-group-prepend` isn't required anymore. Remove the `div` and place `input-group-text` and `form-control` together as siblings.

Comment: thanks @Jordan!

to get the left corners rounded i needed to remove the `label` tag and move the label text into the `aria-label` tag of the `input` element